# How to convert json date with timezone offset to UTC, while mapping to controller request object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson2

I'm working on Spring Boot application and I have a date in JSON request with timezone offset (1968-07-21T23:00:00.000+02:00) and its getting mapped to a LocalDateTime object which is part of a wrapper object without any issue. But I want the date to get adjusted to UTC dynamically while it gets mapped to this request object in controller. So after I get the request wrapper object in controller the value of this date should be "1968-07-22T01:00:00.000+00:00", with date and hours adjusted automatically.

I have tried several things for this but nothing worked, few of the things what I tried so far are as below,

Approach 1 : Since I'm using Jackson 2, I annotated the DTO date field as below

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", timezone="UTC")
```

Approach 2 : I tried customizing Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer as below.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer init() {
return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
  @Override
  public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    builder.timeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
  }
 };
}
```

But both above didn't work for me. Please let me know if there is any other way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a question, does jackson version you are using supports the LocalDateTime?

Comment: Try using a LocalDateTimeFormatter

Comment: Without having the experience myself I suggest that the solution is combining an `OffsetDateTime` with [FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8). Then you won’t need the poorly designed and long outdated `TimeZone` class anymore.

Comment: Didn’t work? What was the outcome of each approach, and how did it differ from the expected?

Comment: @OleV.V., the approach only works properly in terms of mapping time and date to a Java Date variable, however I'm looking for a way which can intervene the process where jackson maps Json to Java date object and convert the date and time as per UTC. Currently the date and time which is getting mapped is not considering the timezone offset that is coming in request JSON "+02:00"

Answer (score 0):

LocalDateTime is a DateTime field without timezone.

From Documentation:

> A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.

Use ZonedDateTime instead.

> date-time with a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00 Europe/Paris.

[javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)

Comment: Yes LocalDateTime doesn't maintain the timezone details, and as per your suggestion I tried ZonedDateTime, but its only mapping the given date and time from JSON request date with UTC timezone and ignoring the timezone offset provided in request, i.e. 1968-07-21T23:00:00.000+02:00 is simply mapped in date object as 1968-07-21T23:00:00.000 with timezone as UTC without any datetime adustment. But in @JsonFormat after adding timezone = "Europe/Riga" it works but that won't dynamically consider offset given in request for timezone

Answer (score 0):

Use the java.text class to do the job.

### for example

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
String date = format.format(new Date());
```

And then send it to your usecase.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.